# Descriptive text under headertext gridview

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

I want to be able to have it so that in a gridview where the header would be bolded as a normal:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Normal Header"></asp:TemplateField>
```

That I can have

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Normal Header<br/>Descriptive Text"></asp:HeaderText>
```

I got the 
 part down because that's easy but I'm really new/bad with CSS elements. Is what I'm looking for possible?

Comment: not sure I follow. Do you just want the Header Text to be bold?

Comment: Well I want the headertext to be bold and then underneath it a description. So sort of like a validator but I want it in the header and always present.. For example if I had a date field and underneath it wanted to put MM/DD/YYYY so users knew that was the appropriate syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HeaderTemplate like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <HeaderTemplate>
           <b>Normal Header</b><br/>
           Descriptive Text
     </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

To unbold the header text, set UseAccessibleHeader to false within the Gridview, this will switch the header to use `<td>` instead of `<th>`.  Then use bold tags or css where needed within the HeaderTemplate.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.useaccessibleheader(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's some discussion about HeaderTemplate:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1628670.aspx?line+break+of+Gridview+s+HeaderText

Comment: This doesn't work because everything is bold. I would like the "Normal Header" to be bold, while the descriptive text is normal. I tested it to be sure though. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Set UseAccessableHeader to false within the Gridview, this will switch the header to use <td> instead of <th>.

Comment: Instead of doing that I added a normal label inside of the header and named the class HTdesc and set the font weight to normal and I'm about to change the text size. It worked like I wanted it to and now I can use the same class on different headers. So your suggestion helped lead to my solution, not sure if yours would've been less time consuming but both work. Thanks